# SQL Combining multiple rows into one column

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

Example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to do]

I'm thinking either using "cases" or a pivot table can help me combine those columns. Assume first table is called "oldTable1" and new table can be called "newTable1".

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a PIVOT operation can help - this is basically “transpose values to columns”. The PIVOT statement is also only available in some RDBMS (make sure to add explicit tag for implementation). Another method is a GROUP BY with an aggregate and CASE. Another is multiple joins (eg. each join is already filtered on the year).

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. The following query would work in most databases:

```
select
    name,
    car,
    max(case when year = 2017 then miles_driven end) miles_driven_2017,
    max(case when year = 2018 then miles_driven end) miles_driven_2018,
    max(case when year = 2019 then miles_driven end) miles_driven_2019,
    max(case when year = 2020 then miles_driven end) miles_driven_2020
from mytable
group by name, car
```

In case there are multiple rows per `(name, car, year)`, you want to use `sum()` instead of `max()`.